# multiple apps in single page in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am buliding an application in angular js.

I have two controllers for two views.

javascript:

```
var myApp1 = angular.module('myApp1', []);
myApp1.controller('myController1', function($scope) {
    alert("check");
    $scope.x = 'test';
});
var myApp2 = angular.module('myApp2', []);
myApp2.controller('myController2', function($scope) {
    alert("check1");
    $scope.x = 'test';
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp1">
            <div ng-controller="myController1">
                <input type="text" ng-model="x" /> {{x}}
            </div>
</div>

<div ng-app="myApp2">
            <div ng-controller="myController2">
                <input type="text" ng-model="x" /> {{x}}
            </div>
</div>
```

only the first controller is getting executed.

Please advice

Comment: you can only have one `module` on a single page.

Comment: I think myApp1.controller('myController2'... should be myApp2.controller('myController2'...

Comment: corrected.but same issue persists

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to bootstrap each app as follows:

```
var myApp1 = angular.module('myApp1', []);
myApp1.controller('myController1', function($scope) {
    alert("check");
    $scope.x = 'test';
});
  angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('myApp1Div'),['myApp1']);


var myApp2 = angular.module('myApp2', []);
myApp2.controller('myController2', function($scope) {
    alert("check1");
    $scope.x = 'test';
});
  angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('myApp2Div'),['myApp2']);
```

And HTML

```
<div id="myApp1Div" >
            <div ng-controller="myController1">
                <input type="text" ng-model="x" /> {{x}}
            </div>
</div>

<div id="myApp2Div" >
            <div ng-controller="myController2">
                <input type="text" ng-model="x" /> {{x}}
            </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V9sYB/59/)

Comment: Sorry.Both the modules are not functioning

Comment: I edit my post. What error do you see in console? Can you set up a jsfiddle?

Comment: Yes I am editing in a jsfiddle and I dont have account right and there is proxy too

Comment: Thanks.It works fine.But doesnt work when the script is given in <head>

Comment: Your can put the script in head but the angular.js script should be load first. View the source and make sure about that.

Comment: I think you shoud change the title of your question to "multiple apps in single page in angular"

Answer (score 4):

use like this

```
var myApp1 = angular.module('myApp1', []);

myApp1.controller('myController1', function($scope) {
    alert("check");
    $scope.x = 'test';
});

myApp1.controller('myController2', function($scope) {
    alert("check1");
    $scope.x = 'test';
});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp1">
            <div ng-controller="myController1">
                <input type="text" ng-model="x" /> {{x}}
            </div>
 <div ng-controller="myController2">
                <input type="text" ng-model="x" /> {{x}}
            </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.But I have to display the two apps in different tabs.

Comment: check out this [define multiple angular apps on single page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12860595/how-to-define-two-angular-apps-modules-in-one-page)

Comment: Any simple example as above?I couldnt understand the complete scope of bootstrap

Comment: check out the description [angular.bootstrap](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap)